# How to clear previous activity stack and Exit Application on back button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities:

```
A,B,C
```

A is home screen.

Activities are launched as follow  `A->B->C`

If I come to home screen using backbutton, I want to clear activity stack/previous activities history and it should exit the application.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very simple: use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` on an intent used to start the activity A.

Comment: Ouch, i misread that you want to clear the history when getting back to A **using the back button**. But still, the only two ways to get to A is either via the back button or via explicitly starting the activity from another. But if you use the mentioned flag when starting the A activity from B or C, then the history gets cleared. And if you just hit back button, it gets cleared one by one, too, so my answer should still solve your problem.

Comment: as i am using backbutton to come to A(Home)screen then this does not make any sense.

Comment: @UMAR: but if you're only using the back button to get Home, any previous activities should be automatically removed from the history as you move away from them. Isn't that so?

Answer (score 4):

You can do following:
1. Set `clearTaskOnLaunch = "true"` in AndroidManifest, in declaration of activity A
2. In activity C:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

So if user presses back - it comes back to homescreen.
If user launches application again - task stack clears and he comes to root activity (A)

Comment: So I don't need to set any intents in order to clear top activities etc if I use the above code you're suggesting? Just "moveTaskToBack" will handle all of it?

Comment: Yes. It allows you to move task to background and show home screen. (but it's still C activity currently active for this task). When user launches you app again- clearTaskOnLaunch works and it removes all activities in your task excepting root activity - so exactly at that moment A becomes active and C destroys.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it still opens some random page or the page that I quit the applicat5ion last when I re-launch it.

Comment: remember  that clearTaskOnLaunch = "true" should be set for _root_ activity, that is launched next time. if your activity is in the middle of a task activities chain - this wouldn't work

Comment: Yep. I did just that and it still doesn't seem to give the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A try this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
                finish();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This should ensure that if you hit the back button the activity is `finish()`ed. If this activity is at the bottom of the stack `finish` should exit the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think compostus is true, but if not, from A you can launch B with startActivityForResult() and in onActivityResult() handle the received "message".
Activity B will send a "CLOSE_ACTIVITY" message if back button has been pressed.